# php glob with absolute url

Tags: php, url-rewriting, glob

I wrote some code to grab images, and worked great until I tried to add some url rewrites.

```
    $image_directory = "/Products/".$ItemName."/";
    $imageArray = array();
    $pictures = glob("$image_directory*", GLOB_BRACE);
    foreach($pictures as $picture)  {
        if (strpos($picture, '400.jpg') !== FALSE){
            if (strpos($picture, 'old') !== FALSE){
            }else{
                $imageArray[] = $picture;
            }
        }
    }
```

Is there a way to add an absolute directory to glob()? Everything I have tried returns either broken links or an empty array.

Comment: `glob($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "{$image_directory}*", GLOB_BRACE);` possibly? Or you could use the **`__DIR__`** constant.

Comment: It did not like either one of those

Comment: What error messages where shown?

Comment: php did not log any errors, but the console log says similar to this for the url that broke http://www.domain.com/home1/xxxxxx/public_html/Products/itemName/itemName400.jpg

Comment: You shouldn't be searching with "domain.com/home1/" etc, it should be the absolute path, which would be something like `xxxxx/public_html/...`

Comment: Correct. $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] is giving me xxxxx/public_html/ but somehow it is getting added to my src for images

Comment: Thanks, I used str_replace to remove that chunk from the src as it gets put into array and now the images work along with the url rewrite